# Теряется сессия при переходе по ссылке

Tags: php, pdo, сессия

Написал страницу, которая после регистрации отправляет на почту письмо, где находится ссылка с подтверждением этой самой почты на моём сайте.

Но вот проблема, не работает страница подтверждения. Теряется сессия.

```
session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);//Убираем Notice, а все остальные ошибки выводим

require_once 'connection.php';

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=dbname', $user, $pass);

$id = $_SESSION['id'];

//var_dump($id);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT code FROM users WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $_SESSION['code'] = $result->code;
}

if($stmt->rowCount() == 0){
    header ('Location: error404.html');
    exit;
}

if($_SESSION['code'] == $_GET['code']){
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE users SET `Activation` = 1 WHERE users.ID = :id');
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
}else{
    header('Location: error404.html');
}
```

Проверяю, что лежит в переменной ID, лежит NULL. Хотя при регистрации все сессии создаются, и человек получает письмо, ссылка в котором открывает другую страницу и запускает сессию.

Comment: сессия живет 24 минуты. все коды писать только в базу

Comment: Для подтверждения почты можно и не использовать сессию, а уникальную строку в адресной строке (записав её предварительно в БД вместе с почтой), и написать адрес с ней в почте. Когда пользователь перейдёт по ссылке, то его почта будет подтверждена. Также можно поставить дату и время иссечения срока годности ссылки и проверять чтобы они не «протухали».

Comment: @DanielProtopopov попытался получить из ссылки типа domane.net/page.php?$code CODE через переменную $_GET['code']. $gCode = $_GET['code'], var_dump($gCode) говорит Null. Такой вопрос. Ссылка по типу domane.net/page.php?$code только при переходе сохраняет переменную? Или она всегда там находится? Даже когда например человек из письма переходит по ссылке domane.net/page.php?123. Просто не могу понять, почему NULL.

Comment: Проверил через print_r($_GET) выводит вот что Array ( [123] => ), но как я понимаю окончательный ответ сервера 0.

Comment: А. Всё. Решил. Переписал код отправки ссылки. И теперь она такого вида domane.net/page.php?code=$code и всё заработало. Спасибо за ответы. Всем всего хорошего.